# How to fix fglrun: symbol lookup error: /u2/acct/d84-lc/obj/4js/lib/userextension.so: undefined symbol: fglcapi_deccvasc

Tags: linux

my 4gl program display this error. i'm using database oracle 11g. This program working fine in old server.

I run command ldd, and here are my findings:

Result in new server:

```
1:1046> ldd /u2/acct/d84-lc/work/EPBT/arpah.e_wb001/all/userextension.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc8b5c1000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007faf0d364000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000557392f4d000)
```

Result in OLD Server:

```
[live:LINUX-x86] ldd userextension.so
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xffffe000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf7d5f000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x00a75000)
```